# Use SWT Browser Widget to Write Desktop Application

Tags: java, browser, swt, widget

I recently played around with the SWT browser widget (which is great). I am wondering if I could write a full desktop application with it (with java services behind - e.g. persistence) and what drawbacks I would have to consider. The advantage would be that people without java knowledge could work on the gui. Of course it depends on the requirements and I know that this is not a very specific question. But mabye someone already tried to build a bigger app this way and is willing to share insights.

Thanks

Marcel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I share your opinion of the SWT browser widget. AFAIK it's merely a shell into the default browser on your machine, merely with a few API access points. I've used it for minor things when I needed to show a web page from within the application. But writing a whole application? That doesn't make sense.

If you want to build a web-based application that runs in the browser against a Java based server framework, there are many AJAXian frameworks to do it. You'd still be doing JavaScript for your client code. And you'd still be dealing with all the complexities of different browsers. I'm not sure why you would want to host it inside an SWT application instead of just directly in the browser window.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know behind the scences the Browser is doing the work. The point is that you can directly call java methods from javascript and vice versa. You wouldn't have to deal with stateless client/server communication and you wouldn't have to delpoy and maintain a server. Would it work for a small standalone application? Regards